# Python script to move oldest 1000 file into another directory

Tags: python-3.x

Here is my code with reads the input from a config file and moving files to another directory based on a condition and logs the information to a log file

```
import shutil
import configparser
import logging.handlers
import os

#Reading the input configuration

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("config_input.ini")
src_filepath = (config.get("Configuration Inputs","src_filepath"))
dst_filepath = (config.get("Configuration Inputs","dst_filepath"))
log_file_name = (config.get("Configuration Inputs","log_file_name"))
file_limit = int((config.get("Configuration Inputs","file_limit")))

if not os.path.exists (dst_filepath):
    os.makedirs(dst_filepath)
onlyfiles_in_dst = next ( os.walk ( dst_filepath ) ) [ 2 ]
file_count_indst = len ( onlyfiles_in_dst )
onlyfiles_in_src = next ( os.walk ( src_filepath ) ) [ 2 ]
file_count_insrc = len ( onlyfiles_in_src )

def sorted_ls(src_filepath):
    mtime = lambda f: os.stat(os.path.join(src_filepath, f)).st_mtime
    return list(sorted(os.listdir(src_filepath), key=mtime))

move_list = sorted_ls(src_filepath)
#print (move_list)
if file_count_indst < file_limit:
    for mfile in move_list:
        shutil.move(src_filepath + '\\' + mfile, dst_filepath)

**#Logging everything**
logger = logging.getLogger()
logging.basicConfig(filename=log_file_name, format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', filemode='a')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.info('Number of files moved from source ' + str(len(move_list)))
```

But the problem is I want to move only the 1000 files from source to destination. 
Something like

> "*ls -lrt| head ls -lrt | head -n 1000*"

which I can not do iy as I am running this script on Windows platform.
Please suggest a proper way to do it.
Also please suggest how can I put it under a user defined class and may be can use in some other program.

Comment: What's the problem exactly with your script? You have file_limit configured? Where do you increase file_count_indst ?

Answer (score 0):

Can't a simple counter be the solution?

```
if file_count_indst < file_limit:
    count=0;
    for mfile in move_list:
        shutil.move(src_filepath + '\\' + mfile, dst_filepath)
        count = count +1
        if count==1000:
            break
```

Comment: `def sorted_ls(src_filepath):
    mtime = lambda f: os.stat(os.path.join(src_filepath, f)).st_mtime
    return list(sorted(os.listdir(src_filepath), key=mtime)[:100])`  -- Figured out using this way

Comment: _Thanks for your input_